# postgresql: How to disable all indexes of a table

Tags: postgresql

There are more than 100 indexes on my table. i want to disable all the indexes temporary and want to re-enabled them once the indexing is done.

It is not feasible to go and type every index name to disable it. is there any PostgreSQL statement which can disable all the indexes temporary and then re-enabled them again.

Regards,

Comment: Why do you need to disable them? Are you doing a bulk import?

Comment: yes i am doing bulk import using select statment

Answer (score 5):

From the Comment, you are doing a bulk import using select..

PostgreSQL has [a guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) on how to best populate a database initially, and they suggest using the [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command for bulk loading rows.  The guide has some other good tips on how to speed up the process, like removing indexes and foreign keys before loading the data (and adding them back afterwards).

> If you are adding large amounts of data to an existing table, it might
>   be a win to drop the indexes, load the table, and then recreate the
>   indexes. Of course, the database performance for other users might
>   suffer during the time the indexes are missing. One should also think
>   twice before dropping a unique index, since the error checking
>   afforded by the unique constraint will be lost while the index is
>   missing.

You can Check [the system catalogue](http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-index.html) to disable an index:

```
update pg_index set indisvalid = false where indexrelid = 'test_pkey'::regclass
```

This means that the index won't be used for queries but will still be updated. It's one of the flags used for concurrent index building.
If you set `indisready` to `false`, that will disable updates.

If you want to disable all for a single query

```
BEGIN;
DROP INDEX foo_ndx;
EXPALIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM foo;
ROLLBACK;
```

You can do this in a transaction to make recovering from it dead simple. You can also disable indexscan to disable all indices.
Also, make sure you are doing `EXPALIN ANALYSE` on your queries.

Comment: "but will still be updated" then there's no point in disabling them.

Comment: Is it EXPLAIN or EXPALIN ?

Comment: Shameless copy & paste of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146109/7304372

Answer (score 3):

If it is helpful to anyone, I have created this procedure to do the trick in a nice clean fashion for an entire schema. It can easily be modified if you want to restrict it to specific tables or other criteria.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE enable_indexes(
    IN schema_name TEXT
,   IN table_name TEXT
,   IN index_name TEXT
,   IN enable_use BOOLEAN
,   IN enable_updates BOOLEAN
,   IN skip_essentials BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
) AS
$$
DECLARE
    each_record RECORD;
BEGIN

IF array_replace(ARRAY[schema_name, table_name, index_name], NULL, '') <@ ARRAY[''] THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Must specify at least one of schema_name | table_name | index_name';
END IF;


FOR each_record IN
    UPDATE pg_index
    SET
        indisvalid = enable_use
    ,   indisready = enable_updates
    FROM pg_indexes
    WHERE
        indexrelid = (schemaname||'.'||indexname)::regclass
    AND case when schema_name <> '' THEN schemaname = schema_name ELSE TRUE END
    AND case when table_name <> '' THEN tablename = table_name ELSE TRUE END
    AND case when index_name <> '' THEN indexname = index_name ELSE TRUE END
    AND case when skip_essentials THEN indisprimary = FALSE ELSE TRUE END
    AND case when skip_essentials THEN indisunique = FALSE ELSE TRUE END
    RETURNING (schemaname||'.'||indexname) as index_name, indisvalid, indisready
LOOP

    RAISE INFO 'Set index % to have use % and updates %.'
        ,   each_record.index_name
        ,   (case when each_record.indisvalid THEN 'enabled' else 'disabled' END)
        ,   (case when each_record.indisready THEN 'enabled' else 'disabled' END)
    ;
END LOOP;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

Example use:

```
call enable_indexes('public', 'table-name', '', TRUE, true);
call enable_indexes('public', '', 'index-name', TRUE, true);
call enable_indexes('public', 'table_name', NULL, TRUE, true);
```

Comment: Do you need to do a REINDEX after re-enabling indexes, or are they rebuilt automatically for any inserts they missed?

Comment: @AndrewWestberg-BCSH The only way to know for sure is to test, but I think you'll need to REINDEX only if you set `enable_updates` to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `pg_indexes`, and `pg_constraint where contype in ('p', 'f')` to get a list of all primary keys, non-PK indices and Foreign keys **and their definitions**.

Using `format()`, run queries to generate all the `DROP INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` statements.

Again using `format()`, run queries to generate the `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` statements.

Drops the constraints and indices before the bulk load, then the CREATE INDEX and ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT statements afterwards (in as many threads as your system can handle).  Note that doing multiple ADD CONSTRAINT statements at the same time might result in one statement blocking another.